# Can't deploy .wsp in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Please don't make fun of me.

I have uploaded and activated a Sharepoint Solution with a 'Hello World' webpart for deployment in a sandbox solution. I used Visual Studio 2008 for development.

The kicker is that I work within the DoD. I had to use my personal laptop that is not connected to the network as a development environment to build the wsp. This is a necessary evil if I want to show 'proof of.concept' and get Visual Studio on my machine at work.

I put the wsp on a disk, and uploaded and activated the solution within Sharepoint 2010. I do not have access to the server. Using Powershell or any of the tools within Central Administration are not an option for me. I am at my wit's end. I don't know.what to do at this point to deploy or incorporate the solution into a Sharepoint page. Suggestions, anyone?

I am new to Sharepoint development, but I am quite comfortable with asp.net/C#. Without access to the Central Administration or even the server for that matter, I am at a loss for what to do next. Please help! Anyone!

Comment: you don't have admin rights, yet expect to be able to do admin-level tasks? good luck...

Comment: Thank you, Captain Obvious! Your brilliant insight has helped me to understand what I already know.  I was hoping for someone to tell me I was possibly missing something, or to tell me that the only way to do what I need, is to deploy the webpart using Visual Studio. Perhaps someone could tell me that without access to Central Admin and Powershell, that deploying the solution manually isn't going to happen? I thought that just MAYBE an experienced Sharepoint developer would tell me something to that effect. Nope. I got lucky! I got Mark B! You're awesome, Mark!

Comment: I finally spoke with a Microsoft consultant. I actually did everything right, however, I did not ensure that the proper configurations were added to the manifest.xml file. That solved the problem. Thanks again, Mark B!

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the wsp to the solutions gallery and activate it you already have it on the site.
So your issue is how to incorporate a components from this solution into your pages ?

activating a solution on sharePoint site is different from deploying it.

if it is to add a component(webpart , customized page ..etc), you just have to make sure that your features are activated.

also if you need to add a webpart you have to:
* edit page ( in the site actions menu)
* click on add webpart ( if your page is a webpart page / verify it is not a wiki page)
* search in the custom section if you need a developed webpart,
* click add then if no further editing is needed just click save and close on the top of the page.

I hope my answer was helpful!

cheers!